# groovy replaceAll with \n

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm working with jobDsl in Jenkins 2

I have a script.dsl with patterns to replace

I'm triying to replace rDEST with desa\ntest

Here my example

```
example="choiceListText('rDEST')"
print ("example is ")
println (example)
exreplace = example.replaceAll("rDEST","desa\ntest")
print ("exreplace is ")
println (exreplace)
```

The code result is

```
example is choiceListText('rDEST')
exreplace is choiceListText('desa
test')
```

I'm expecting to get

```
exreplace is choiceListText('desa\ntest')
```

I've tried Single quoted, Triple single quoted, Double quoted, Triple double quoted but stil cant get it done!

Comment: No idea is this even doable.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code

```
example="choiceListText('rDEST')"
print ("example is ")
println (example)
exreplace = example.replaceAll("rDEST","desa \\\\n test")
print ("exreplace is ")
println (exreplace)
```

Because 
This "\\" is for the slash
This "\\" other one is for \n which also is a reserved character

And i also had to write 3 slashes to post my answer!!!

Thanks to Marcelo Gaston Rebasti Peralta!!!